# how do I fill a form using jquery-ui-1.8.21.autocomplete and data from mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm successfully retrieving one field from my mysql DB using jquery-ui-autocomplete, but I need to take the user's selection from the list, re-select from the DB and fill normally more than one form with the addresses retrieved from the DB.

Here is the code I have working so far, but I don't know how to continue, to get the results I need. The scenario is this - I have an INPUT field which populates with zip codes retrieved from the DB. The user then selects a zip code and from that selection I need all addresses out of the DB to populate individual forms.

my HTML file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                    autoFocus: true,
                    source: "search.php",
                    minLength: 2, //search after two characters
                    select: function(event, ui){
                        //do something
                        }
                    });
            });

<body>
    <input id="autocomplete" type="text" name="autocomplete" />
</body>
```

my search.php file:

```
// DB connection is done here

$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

$qstring = "SELECT DISTINCT zipcode FROM table WHERE zipcode LIKE '%".$term."%' ORDER BY zipcode ASC";
$result = mysql_query($qstring); //query the database for entries containing the term

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) //loop through the retrieved values
{
$row['zipcode'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['zipcode']));
$row['id'] = (int)$row['id'];
$row_set[] = $row['zipcode']; //build an array
}

echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
```

I use DISTINCT in my query of course to eliminate multiple same zip codes.

Thank you for your help!
Robert

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use ajax. It will perform your search the same way it performs your autocomplete searches. The 'select' event will run whenever an autocomplete selection is made. If the user types in the full zipcode without using the autocomplete, I do not believe it will trigger. The 'change' event triggers upon leaving the field. It won't trigger until the user leaves the autocomplete field.

```
select: function(event, ui){

    $.ajax({
        url: "otherSearch.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { input1 : input1,
                input2 : input2 },
        success: function(data) {

            //parse returned data and fill in the forms

            });
        }
    }
}
```

more info on ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/